# How to Automatically update name servers and validate an SSL certificate with CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

AWS documentation claims that if I have a registered domain in another DNS registar that then I have to updated the name servers on the registered domain so presumably I thought that if I created a hosted zone by specifying a domain registered on R53 that the name servers will be updated automatically. This is the part of my CloudFormation:

```
   HostedZone:
    Type: "AWS::Route53::HostedZone"
    Properties:
      Name: example.com
```

I have indeed registered example.com on R53 yet when I go to the domain it has different name servers from its hosted zone SOA record.

Also the documentation claims if I do this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-aws-certificate-manager-with-aws-cloudformation/

Which I did like this:

```
  SSLCertificate:
    Type: AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate
    Properties:
      DomainName: example.com
      ValidationMethod: DNS
      DomainValidationOptions:
        - DomainName: example.com
          HostedZoneId: !Ref HostedZone
```

It says that the SSL certificate should have been verified automatically yet the stack stops here and I have to go to the certificate manager (After updating name servers of course) and click on "Import to R53" (the CNAME) even though the CNAME was automatically created in the Hosted Zone but with wrong values and then the stack continues forward.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Wrong CNAME records” could be the keyword here, have you tried to remove the certificate resource from the CF template, update the stavk with it, clean up the CNAME entries, make sure the certificate is deleted from ACM and then add the Certificate resource again to the CF template?

My guess goes in a direction how CloudFormation works on updating resources. For Certificates most changes require recreation, meaning First create a new one and then, whenever the new certificate is created successfully, delete the old one.
This behaviour males sense but sometimes causes issues.

Also make sure the `DomainName` is the same as in the `Validation` properties field. The following template fails to validate due to that wrong configuration:

```yaml
Resources:
  Certificate:
    Type: AWS::CertificateManager::Certificate
    Properties:
      DomainName: www.example.com
      DomainValidationOptions:
      - DomainName: example.com
        HostedZoneId: !Ref Zone
      ValidationMethod: DNS
```

Comment: I was able to set it up so that it creates a correct CNAME (I don't know what I changed, I added www. in front of A record domain name  and one of Domain names in Certificate resource) but it won't validate (I tried changing name server on registered domain  manually and it still didn't validate). If my domain is registered as example.com should I create a www.example.com hosted zone. I am creating also a A record set and that cert should be attached to a ALB listener.

Comment: Just one hint, you don't need a Hosted Zone for every subdomain. One Zone is sufficient, just create records and put the name (e.g. www) for the record. Verify with `nslookup www.example.com`

Comment: I knwo that, I created an A record with the same name as the domain in this case. Hosted zone is created for the man domain registered on R53. But CF can't build it because the ACM resource fails later on.

Comment: I was able to re-produce the issue with updating the `DomainName` but not the Validation Domain name. Then the CName entries are obviously not created